# LLVM build using cmake fails during tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc; "Error: conflicting types for ..."

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, cilk

I have at least successfully configured the build for the llvm compiler according to the directions [here](http://cilkplus.github.io/).

When I go to build using `cmake --build . -v` I get the following error output:

```
$ cmake --build . -v
...
[ 63%] Building CXX object projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc.o
cd /Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/build/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan && /usr/bin/clang++ --sysroot=/  -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Dclang_rt_tsan_osx_dynamic_EXPORTS -I/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/build/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan -I/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan -I/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/build/include -I/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/include -I/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/..  -isystem / -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64h -fPIC    -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fPIC -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fno-sanitize=safe-stack -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-function-sections -fno-lto -O3 -gline-tables-only -Wno-gnu -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-c99-extensions -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -fPIE -fno-rtti -msse3 -Wframe-larger-than=512 -Wglobal-constructors -o CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc.o -c /Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc
/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:144:22: error: 
      conflicting types for 'dispatch_sync'
DISPATCH_INTERCEPT_B(dispatch_sync)
                     ^
/usr/include/dispatch/queue.h:292:1: note: previous declaration is here
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t queue, DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block);
^
/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:145:22: error: 
      conflicting types for 'dispatch_barrier_sync'
DISPATCH_INTERCEPT_B(dispatch_barrier_sync)
                     ^
/usr/include/dispatch/queue.h:1278:1: note: previous declaration is here
dispatch_barrier_sync(dispatch_queue_t queue,
^
/Users/anthonymcknight/Documents/cubing/bfs/lab4/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:162:24: error: 
      conflicting types for 'dispatch_once'
TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_once, dispatch_once_t *predicate,
                       ^
/usr/include/dispatch/once.h:73:1: note: previous declaration is here
dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
^
3 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I was previously able to workaround buggy compiler flags set by cmake by simply copying and pasting the verbose output and correcting it in the command line, but I'm not sure what to edit here to get things to work.

I've tried changing -isysroot, copying and pasting header files into llvm/include from /usr/include or the MacOSX10.14.sdk file, and the persistent issue is the `error: conflicting types ...`

I've even tried doing small modifications to tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc but none of them worked (e.g., changing `#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>` to `#include <dispatch.h>`, changing "user_alloc" to "user_alloc_internal"...).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Anthony

Comment: What compiler (and what version) are you using?

Comment: clang & clang++:
```clang --version``` & ```clang++ --version``` => Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)

Answer (score 1):

Basically I had to replace my original tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc with the one form [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D38141). I have yet to complete the full installation, much less test performance, but my build is proceeding past this point now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to compile it for llvm 3.9.1 but the tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc is different. Here's a diff that works:

```
diff --git a/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc b/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc
index 529cedba4..86982e361 100644
--- a/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc
+++ b/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc
@@ -144,7 +144,7 @@ static void invoke_and_release_block(void *param) {
   }

 #define DISPATCH_INTERCEPT_SYNC_B(name, barrier)                             \
-  TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, name, dispatch_queue_t q, dispatch_block_t block) { \
+  TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, name, dispatch_queue_t q, DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block) { \
     SCOPED_TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(name, q, block);                                 \
     SCOPED_TSAN_INTERCEPTOR_USER_CALLBACK_START();                           \
     dispatch_block_t heap_block = Block_copy(block);                         \
@@ -234,7 +234,7 @@ TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_after_f, dispatch_time_t when,
 // need to undefine the macro.
 #undef dispatch_once
 TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_once, dispatch_once_t *predicate,
-                 dispatch_block_t block) {
+                 DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block) {
   SCOPED_INTERCEPTOR_RAW(dispatch_once, predicate, block);
   atomic_uint32_t *a = reinterpret_cast<atomic_uint32_t *>(predicate);
   u32 v = atomic_load(a, memory_order_acquire);
@@ -444,7 +444,7 @@ TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_source_set_registration_handler_f,
 }

 TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_apply, size_t iterations,
-                 dispatch_queue_t queue, void (^block)(size_t)) {
+                 dispatch_queue_t queue, DISPATCH_NOESCAPE void (^block)(size_t)) {
   SCOPED_TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(dispatch_apply, iterations, queue, block);

   void *parent_to_child_sync = nullptr;
```